# Publish WordPress Post with Python Requests and REST API

Tags: python, wordpress, rest

I try to publish post to WordPress blog with python requests and rest api by following code:

```
auth = 'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(b'admin:123456'), 'utf-8')
headers = {'Authorization': auth}
body = {'title': 'Hello World'}
r = requests.post('wp-json/wp/v2/posts', headers=headers, data=body)
```

and always got 401 error:

```
>>> r.text
'{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}'
```

I'm pretty sure that the account admin and password is correct and has administrator role, Did I miss anything?

Comment: it's a shame, I forgot to activate basic auth plugin:)

Comment: What do you mean "you forgot to activate basic auth plugin"? I am trying to post to my wordpress site and I am facing the same error... {"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}'

Comment: Have you considered using the XMLRPC-API? It's very simple, here's an example: http://sinajahangiri.com/2017/06/18/how-to-use-python-to-write-a-post-in-your-wordpress-websiteblog/

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this

1. I installed & activated this plugin on my wordpress
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/
2. follow the help text there and create your password string for your userid - assume it is mypassword123
3. now do this on your terminal
   "admin:mypassword123" | base64

You will get a new password - say pwdabc123

4. Code looks like

```py
url_srcdest = "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          'Authorization': 'Basic pwdabc123',
          'Username': '<your username>', 
          'Password':'pwdabc123'}
data = \
    {
        "title":"Testing via API via Python",
        "content":"tEST CONTENT OF THE THIS TEST PAGE via PYTHON",
        "status": "publish"
    }

response = requests.post(url_srcdest, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: For some people (me) this is only a partial solution... it leads to an issue with "Basic Authorization Headers missing" ... the quest for a working solution continues at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328304/still-getting-basic-authorization-header-missing-error-after-updating-htacces

Comment: Does not work. Not sure if this ever worked, but not reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

you missed:

- `auth` **IS** your `jwt token`, **NOT** `base64 encode token`

  - `jwt token` is got from `POST /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`

## How to get `jwt token` ?

### prerequisite

#### installed jwt plugin

install and enable WordPress plugin:

- [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)

  - [image: JWT Authentication for WP REST API]

#### wordpress server enable jwt authorization

for example, my wordpress server is: `CentOS`

1. edit `.htaccess` in wordpress root folder

added:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

2. edit `wp-config.php`

add:

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'anyValueIsOk');
```

- `anyValueIsOk`: change to yours, any value is OK

  - just do NOT tell other, ^_^
- Remember `service php-fpm restart` after edit php file

### POST `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` to generate jwt token

call REST api to generate jwt token

```
POST https://www.yourWebsite.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token

{
    "username": "wordpress_username",
    "password": "wordpress_password"
}
```

- `wordpress_username`: here is your `admin`
- `wordpress_password`: here is your `123456`

response:

```json
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOxxxxxxxxxxxxHYBhtuzc",
    "user_email": "xxx@yyy.com",
    "user_nicename": "xxx",
    "user_display_name": "xxx"
}
```

- `eyJ0eXAiOxxxxxxxxxxxxHYBhtuzc`: is the **jwt token**, which is what your need

#### [Optional] validate token is valid

```
POST https://www.crifan.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate

headers:
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOxxxxxxxxxxxxHYBhtuzc
```

response:

```json
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_valid_token",
    "data": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

## Additionally: use python call wordpress REST api to create posts

code:

```py
import requests

your_jwt_token = "xxx"

curHeaders = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % your_jwt_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

categoryIdList = []
tagIdList = []

if categoryNameList:
    # ['Mac']
    categoryIdList = self.getTaxonomyIdList(categoryNameList, taxonomy="category")
    # category nameList=['Mac'] -> taxonomyIdList=[1374]

if tagNameList:
    # ['切换', 'GPU', 'pmset', '显卡模式']
    tagIdList = self.getTaxonomyIdList(tagNameList, taxonomy="post_tag")
    # post_tag nameList=['切换', 'GPU', 'pmset', '显卡模式'] -> taxonomyIdList=[1367, 13224, 13225, 13226]

postDict = {
    "title": title, # '【记录】Mac中用pmset设置GPU显卡切换模式'
    "content": content, # '<div>\n  折腾：\n </div>\n <div>\n  【已解决】Mac Pro 2018款发热量大很烫非常烫\n </div>\n <div>\n  期间，...performance graphic cards\n    </li>\n   </ul>\n  </ul>\n </ul>\n <div>\n  <br/>\n </div>'
    # "date_gmt": dateStr,
    "date": dateStr, # '2020-08-17T10:16:34'
    "slug": slug, # 'on_mac_pmset_is_used_set_gpu_graphics_card_switching_mode'
    "status": status, # 'draft'
    "format": postFormat, # 'standard'
    "categories": categoryIdList, # [1374]
    "tags": tagIdList, # [1367, 13224, 13225, 13226]
    # TODO: featured_media, excerpt
}

yourHost = 'https://www.crifan.com'
createPostUrl = yourHost + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" # 'https://www.crifan.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'

resp = requests.post(
    createPostUrl,
    # proxies=self.requestsProxies,
    headers=curHeaders,
    # data=json.dumps(postDict),
    json=postDict, # internal auto do json.dumps
)
```

response example:

```json
{
  "id": 70410,
  "date": "2020-02-27T21:11:49",
  "date_gmt": "2020-02-27T13:11:49",
  "guid": {
      "rendered": "https://www.crifan.com/?p=70410",
      "raw": "https://www.crifan.com/?p=70410"
  },
  "modified": "2020-02-27T21:11:49",
  "modified_gmt": "2020-02-27T13:11:49",
  "password": "",
  "slug": "mac_pip_change_source_server_to_spped_up_download",
  "status": "draft",
  "type": "post",
  "link": "https://www.crifan.com/?p=70410",
  "title": {
      'raw": "【已解决】Mac中给pip更换源以加速下载",
      "rendered": "【已解决】Mac中给pip更换源以加速下载"
  },
  "content": {
      ...
  }
}
```

Note:

- latest full code:

  - https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/thirdParty/crifanWordpress.py

    - `createPost`
- wordpress official doc: [Create a Post](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post)

---

more detail pls refer my Chinese posts:

- [【已解决】用Python发布印象笔记帖子内容到WordPress网站](https://www.crifan.com/publish_evernote_post_content_to_wordpress_website_with_python)
- [【已解决】用Python发布帖子到WordPress用什么库和调用哪些接口](https://www.crifan.com/what_libraries_interfaces_used_publish_posts_wordpress_with_python)
- [【已解决】用Python通过WordPress的REST的API发布文章post](https://www.crifan.com/use_python_publish_article_posts_through_wordpress_rest_api)
- [【已解决】给crifan.com的WordPress网站REST的API添加JWT的token认证](https://www.crifan.com/add_jwt_token_authentication_rest_api_crifan_com_wordpress_website)
- [【已解决】WordPress的jwt-auth用Postman去测试生成token和验证token](https://www.crifan.com/wordpress_jwt_auth_uses_postman_test_generation_verification_tokens)
- [【已解决】Python把印象笔记帖子内容通过WordPress的REST的post接口去上传到crifan.com](https://www.crifan.com/python_uploads_evernote_post_content_crifan_com_through_wordpress_rest_post_interface)

Answer (score 3):

*Up to date and working solution as of 2022*

Use Application Passwords as the authorization method. This type of authorization is built-in into wordpress now.

In your Wordpress dashboard navigate to `Users` and choose your profile, scroll down to the `Application Passwords` and generate a new password.

Once that is done, perform a POST request like so

```py
import requests # run "pip install requests" if not yet installed.

ROOT = '<Your WEBSITE URL ROOT>'
AUTH_USER = '<USERNAME>'
AUTH_PASSWORD = '<XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX>'


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {
        "title":"Test Post",
        "content":"Testing via Python.",
        "status": "publish"
    }

r = requests.post(url= ROOT + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', data=data, headers=headers, auth=(AUTH_USER, AUTH_PASSWORD))
```

Your should see the new post inside Wordpress.

Comment: I followed these exact steps and I'm STILL getting that same Mod_Security error. The Wordpress blog is installed on a Hostgator website, could that be the issue? Tried disabling modsecurity in every .htaccess file I could find, as many recommend, and it's still not resolving the issue...

Comment: This doesn't appear to work and generates an error of: 401
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}

Answer (score 0):

I just use `requests` as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), along with the application password:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://example-wp.com/wp-json/', auth=('username', 'APPLICATIONPASSWORD'))
r.status_code
```