# How can I post response to WordPress via REST API?

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm trying to post OpenAI's response (content message) as the content for my WordPress post, however, the WordPress part of my code doesn't seem to work, I've played around with doing it different ways but no post is created as a draft, how can I get OpenAI's response as the content of my drafted WordPress post?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import openai
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import random
import base64


# Array holding wordpress author IDs
authorList = ["1", "2"]

# Randomly choose a number from authorList array
randomAuthor = random.choice(authorList)

# Set OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = ""

# Then, you can call the "gpt-3.5-turbo" model
modelEngine = "gpt-3.5-turbo"

# set your input text
inputText = "Write a 500 word tweet on {} stock"

inputTitle = "Test analyst on {}"

# Array of keywords to generate article on
keywords = ["Nio (NIO)", "Apple (AAPL)", "Microsoft (MSFT)", "Tesla (TSLA)", "Meta (META)", "Amazon (AMZN)"]

# WordPress information
wp_base_url = ""

#auth = HTTPBasicAuth("", "")
wp_username = ""
wp_password = ""

auth = wp_username + ':' + wp_password
token = base64.b64encode(auth.encode())

# Post creator function
def create_post(title, content, authorList):
    post_status = "draft"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic" + token.decode('utf-8')
        #"Accept": "application/json",
        #"Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    post = json.dumps({
        "title": title,
        "content": content,
        "status": post_status,
        "author": authorList
    })
    url = wp_base_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    response = requests.post(url, json=post, headers=headers)
    return response

# Switches and injects keywords into API request
for keyword in keywords:
    # set input text with the current keyword
    inputSent = inputText.format(keyword)
    inputTitleSent = inputTitle.format(keyword)
    # Send an API request and get a response, note that the interface and parameters have changed compared to the old model
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model=modelEngine,
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": inputSent }],
    n = 1
    )

    print("ChatGPT API replies for", keyword, "stock:\n")
    for choice in response.choices:
        outputText = choice.message
        print(outputText)
        print("------")
        # Create the WordPress post using the OpenAI response
        create_post(inputTitleSent, choice.message, randomAuthor)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your set-up? Are there two servers involved? One hosting WordPress and a second using Python? If the Python request is coming from the same server as the one hosting WordPress, is there a reason the API request could not be written in PHP as part of a WordPress plugin?

Comment: @kofeigen The wordpress site is hosted on SiteGrounds and I'm currently using my local computer to send the request. Is this achievable?

Comment: I would think what you are trying to achieve is possible. But, WordPress uses cookies to manage the session. How did you plan to receive and resend cookies from WordPress?

Comment: This is a question about Wordpress API, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532738/publish-wordpress-post-with-python-requests-and-rest-api

Comment: @picsoung thanks for linking that question. Problem is solved, followed comment by zenahr